# concat two fields activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm so used to oracle where you can simply

```
concat(field1, ' ', field2)
```

but if I'm using activerecord to find the field1 and field2, and I need a space in between, how do I accomplish this?

Cheers for all your help

Answer (score 10):

in your model:

```
def full_name
  [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
end
```

Comment: can this be used strictly for just displaying in a select tag?

Comment: no, it just returns a string of two concatenated fields, so anywhere you want to use it.

Comment: by chance, how do I actually write that if I have something like this, which is the first select which has the name and the second select which is the price...

    select "sales", "name", Sales.find(:all, :select => 'DISTINCT name', :order => 'price').collect{|x| [ x.name]}

Comment: you need to clarify the question in order for me to understand what you are asking

Comment: Well okay, I wanted to concat price and name together to form one select tag instead of the two I have already.  I was wondering how they this ties with the example that you gave me.  I'm new to ruby, but I've been spending a lot of time trying to get this working :S

Comment: In your model: 

     class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
       def name_and_price
         [price, name].join(' ')
       end
     end

In your view:
`collection_select(:post, :author_id, Product.all, :id, :name_with_price)`

Answer (score 8):

For posterity and future googlers, you can do the following assuming postgres(maybe mysql?):

```
User.select("(first_name || ' ' || last_name) as name").where(organization: current_user.organization)
```

The select uses the `||` [SQL operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) to concat the strings from the fields `first_name` and `last_name`, and `as name` returns the result in a column "name".

Which might return:

```
+----+--------------------+
| id | name               |
+----+--------------------+
| 3  | Ada Lovelace       |
| 18 | Alan Turing        |
+----+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I think virtual attributes are right up your alley. [This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) explains them, with an example that looks just like your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#` when joining two field with different datatypes.

For instance, adding one integer and string with `+` will give an error.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Chase Gilliam response, this is the query for a MySQL DB

```
User.select("id, CONCAT(name, last_name) as value")
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

My solution: :)

```
scope :full_name_contains, lambda { |query| 
  full_name = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('concat', [
      arel_table[:first_name], 
      Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' '), 
      arel_table[:last_name]
    ]
  )

  where(full_name.matches("%#{query}%"))
}

def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```